# Autofac lifetime events

Tags: autofac

I know I can subscribe to different lifetime events: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/events.html

but does Autofac provide an event that is raised upon registration?

i.e. OnRegistered

it would be very handy on Assembly Scanning.

I should mention I use Autofac 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the OnRegistered event?

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()).OnRegistered(e =>
{
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Seems like a joke from my side, but when I wrote the question I actually searched the github repo for exactly that event.

Anyway... thank you. You helped me :)